# dialog Framework is not firing a close event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I open dialog in the bean method like that

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/pageName.xhtml", options, null);
```

it's inside `actionListener` of button clicked.

There is also a "close" button on the `pageName.xhtml` which executes:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
```

But dialog is not being closed. What I need actually is to catch a close event, but I can't use `<p:ajax event="close"/>` since I don't have `p:dialog` element and I couldn't manage it with `<p:ajax event="dialogReturn"/>` placed inside `p:commandButton` which opens the dialog.

I also tried to add a `widgetVar` in option-map when opening and call

```
PF('widgetVarName').hide();
```

on click. No result.

Option `closable` set to `true` puts a cross on right top of the dialog window, which closes the dialog, yes, but, it didn't fire a close event.

So the question is: **How can I close the dialog and execute some code after?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton id="openDialogButton" value="open dialog" action="#{myBean.openDialog('origin')}">
    <!-- dialogReturn event: data could be passed, see page 587 in PF 6.1 manual. -->
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{myBean.doSthOnDialogReturn}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

**myDialogPage.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog" value="close dialog"
   action="#{myBean.closeDialog('false')}"/>

<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog2" value="close dialog 2"
    action="#{myBean.closeDialog('true')}"
    ajax="false" validateClient="true"/>
```

Note: Example shows how to pass parameter from dialog. You can also notice, that the first button does just return while the second one does validation at first. I think these things can be useful.

**myBean.java**

```
public void openDialog(String origin) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("myDialogPage",
    options, null);
}

public void closeDialog(Boolean param) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(param);
}

public void doSthOnDialogReturn(SelectEvent event) {
    if ((Boolean) event.getObject()) { // retrieve param value
        doSth();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also fire the closeDialog method when the 'x'  close button is used at the top right corner?

Answer (score 0):

Hello everybody and future me,

remember to put your Buttons in a From ;-)

```
<h:form id="myformid">
<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog" value="close dialog"
   action="#{myBean.closeDialog('false')}"/>

<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog2" value="close dialog 2"
    action="#{myBean.closeDialog('true')}"
    ajax="false" validateClient="true"/>
</h:form>
```